# Back-inferring of parameter types from Parameterized generic argument

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have this initial code base

```
public class BaseValue {}

public class ValueHolder<KeyT extends Comparable, ValueT extends BaseValue> {
    public KeyT key;
    public ValueT value;
}

public class ValueProcessor<ValueHolderT extends ValueHolder> {
    public void doSomethingWith(ValueHolderT value) {
    }
}

public class Process {
    public <ValueT extends BaseValue, ValueHolderT extends ValueHolder<?,ValueT>> 
            void run(ValueHolderT value, ValueProcessor<ValueHolderT> processor) {
        processor.doSomethingWith(value);
    }
}

public class Client {
    public static void test() {
        ValueHolder<String,BaseValue> value = null;
        ValueProcessor<ValueHolder<String,BaseValue>> processor = null;

        new Process().run(value, processor);
    }
}
```

So ... there is some kind of processing where matching of value type is verified at build time.

At some point of time, when plenty of code is already using such design of ValueProcessor I notice that I'm missing any result from the processor - I'm going to fix that by returning Key of the processed item.
To make this work I'm going to change code like this (now I return value.key):

```
public class ValueProcessor<KeyT extends Comparable, ValueHolderT extends ValueHolder<KeyT,?>> {
    public KeyT doSomethingWith(ValueHolderT value) {
        return value.key;
    }
}
```

but this change will require consecutive change in all the code where ValueProcessor was used (because new template argument was added)

```
public class Process {
    public <KeyT extends Comparable, ValueT extends BaseValue, ValueHolderT extends ValueHolder<KeyT,ValueT>> 
            void run(ValueHolderT value, ValueProcessor<KeyT, ValueHolderT> processor) {
        processor.doSomethingWith(value);
    }
}

public class Client {
    public static void test() {
        ValueHolder<String,BaseValue> value = null;
        ValueProcessor<String,ValueHolder<String,BaseValue>> processor = null;

        new Process().run(value, processor);
    }
}
```

... and let's say this occurs in 1000th of places -> to many changes, mess in the code because of excessive number of template arguments, but ...

This is actually not needed, KeyT type argument (String in my sample) is already defined for ValueHolder and just duplicated for ValueProcessor.
I would write my code as following (see `as KeyT`), but that syntax is not accepted.

```
public class ValueProcessor<ValueHolderT extends ValueHolder<? {{{as KeyT}}},?>> {
    public KeyT doSomethingWith(ValueHolderT value) {
        return value.key;
    }
}
```

And the question - Is this somehow possible in Java syntax?

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: noooo.  There's no way around this.

Comment: :) i was hoping for more encouraging reply. May it be possible in Java9?

Comment: Almost certainly not.